# how to store an array in the db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to store an array in one field of a db. I know how to do that technically. My questions is, which version makes sense to do that.

First a short introduction:
I have categories in a table and need translations for each category for all languages. To start, I have 2 languages (later I will have more). Ok, let's say my category is car and the structure is like that:

```
id    name    translation
```

My first idea was:

```
id    name    translation
1     car     array('eng' => 'car', 'deu' => 'Auto')
```

The second idea was:

```
id    name    translation
1     car     'eng' => 'car', 'deu' => 'Auto'
```

The third idea was:

```
id    name    translation
1     car     'eng'='car','deu'='Auto'
```

At the end, the script reads the translation cell and loads into an array and returns the value for the given key 'eng' or 'deu' or whatever it comes later.

I use PHP / MySQL

Thank you for any pros and cons.

Ivo

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: maybe [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and put that in your column?

Comment: The point is, I have to translate the categories. I can't do columns for each language - otherwise I have to change the code everytime another language is coming to the system. With my idea, I can update only one column.

Comment: you should then have a new column named language specifying which language the stored string corresponds to and add one line per translated value

Comment: The usual way of doing this that won't end up in a pickle is to add another table. Change `translation` (a string) to `translation_id` (an int) and then point that to a `category_lang` table. That will have a PK of `(translation_id, lang)` and a column of `name` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting your database structure. This might be ideal:

```
id    name    language    word
1     car     eng         car
2     car     deu         Auto

Primary Key (`name`,`language`)
Unique Key (`id`) (auto_increment)
```

In this way you can have as many (or as few) languages as you like.

Comment: I would also recommend the OP use standard language/culture codes instead of arbitraty ones ie. `en_US` or `en`, `de_DE` or `de` etc.

Comment: thank you prodigitalson, I will do that. Is there a table with all of the codes?

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol: In this special case, this is not possible, because I have subcategories in the same table (I would loose the ids).

Comment: I thought it's best I take this codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes

Comment: i always use the [IETF language tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) which is essentially a combination of the shortest 639-1 code and the country code (tehcnically there is more to it than that but that is pretty much what it boils down to for the majority of common locales).

Answer (score 2):

You need to go about this completely different. Add another table, `category_translation`.

You'd have `category`:

```
id    name
```

and `language`:

```
id    name
```

and `category_translation`:

```
id    lang_id    category_id    translation
```

This way you'll have things beautifully separated.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a translation table, with the language being one of the columns.
id, name, language, value
1, car, eng, car
2, car, deu, Auto
...

if you only have a single set of values, you can keep everything in this table. if you are looking up multiple values from different sources you can either add a lookup key to this table, or use the name as your lookup value (though indexing on text will not be as good as indexing on integer IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not store an array in your database in one column. At least serialize if it you have to do it

```
serialize($array)
```